# Drawing shapes on a panel

Tags: java, drawing

I'm a beginner in Java and I wanted to draw multiple shapes on a panel with a `mouseMotionListener()` and `mouseListener()`.

Problem is, whenever I get it to draw a shape, it overwrites on the shape I drew before. The codes I've seen on books seem to work when they're not event oriented and their codes are written from the same class.

Can someone write me a concise example? Thanks a lot!

Comment: So without seeing any code, we're going to guess that your problem lies on line 42 of your DrawPanel class. Please use common sense when asking questions, including realizing when code is necessary to be shown. Regarding, "can someone write me a concise example?" there are plenty to be found if you put in a little effort to look.

Comment: Please see [this search result](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bswing%5D+drawing+shapes+jpanel) for example, some answered by myself. Also for future reference, please have a look at the [help] as well as the [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections for more information on how to improve your future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> whenever I get it to draw a shape, it overwrites on the shape I drew before.

There are two common ways to draw shapes on a panel:

1. Keep an `ArrayList` of the shapes you want to draw and then iterates through the ArrayList to paint each shape
2. Paint the shapes onto a `BufferedImage`.

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for working examples of both of these approaches.